# AS3 - Access of possibly undefined variable

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, oop, class

I have a class called "Character". Some Characters are playable (playable = true). All of the playable characters have a child movieClip called 'follower' (not created with ActionScript). Whenever I try to access 'follower' with code, I get an error, because 'follower' does not 'necessarily' exist. This is because there are some Characters that do not have a 'follower'.

However, I have used 'if (this.contains(follower)) { .. }' to ensure that it does exist before continuing, but I still get the error saying 'follower' might not exist.

Why am I getting the error?
Can I do anything about it? Must I use AS3 to create followers instead?

Comment: try "if (follower!=null) {...}"

Comment: you have many typos to many parens and it is not a string so use this. if (this.contains(follower))

Comment: Sorry, I have been actually using the right syntax, I just posted it wrong in this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can access 'follower' like this: `this["follower"]` - so you won't be getting compile time errors.

Also, you could check `playable` property instead of checking if `follower` exists.

Comment: this["follower"] - will still generate a runtime error.  Between the two, a compile time error is MUCH better as you can detect the problem before the project goes to production... runtime means the client will see it!

Comment: @Reshape Media you're right about runtime errors. However, if the code checks if `this["follower"]` exists there should be no runtime errors. Although, if there is a need of doing such a workaround it means a flaw in design.

Comment: agreed, workarounds are usually flaws.  "follower" should be sub-classed to some extent, but because I see [this.contains] - leads me to believe its rendered in Flash IDE and not Eclipse = very little class declarations.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a public `follower` variable in your Character class (type MovieClip).
This will be null in non-playable characters, and will be set to the sub clip in playable characters.

This only works if you have 'Automatically declare stage instances' turned off.

Answer (score 0):

Inside The `Character` class:

```
if(this["follower"]) {
    // follower instance exists
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is missing some information, is this an AS2/AS3 project (based on your question).  If so the problem is because AS3 cannot access AS2 content.

"Must I use AS3 to create followers instead?" - if its an AS3 project, yes please do.

If your project is both AS2/3, try to use LocalConnection to control the 'follower' clip.  If I am incorrect in my assumption, please correct me.